# Can't figure out why SQL statement isn't woking

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I can't understand what's wrong with my statement. Seems right to me, and the cursor should include both rows in my database table. According to SQLite website this formatted date is supported (Also tried with other supported dates).

```
        String statement = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DISTANCE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_TIME_DISTANCE_ADDED + " BETWEEN " + "2014-07-14" + " AND " + "2014-08-14";
        Log.d("statement", statement);
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(statement, null);
        Log.d("cursor amount rows", Integer.toString(cur.getCount()));

        if (cur != null) {
            cur.moveToFirst();
        }    
        int totalDistance = 0;
        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            Log.d("cursor distance value", Integer.toString(cur.getInt(0)));
            totalDistance += cur.getInt(0);
            cur.moveToNext();
        }
        Log.d("Total Distance traveled = ", Integer.toString(totalDistance));
```

This is what the table looks like.
[image: This is what my table looks like]

Log:

```
...statement﹕ SELECT * FROM distanceTraveled WHERE timedistadded BETWEEN 2014-07-14 AND 2014-08-14

com.example.RoadTrip D/cursor amount rows﹕ 0
com.example.RoadTrip D/Total Distance traveled =﹕ 0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try quoting you query paramaters

e.g.

```
+ "'2014-07-14'" + " AND " + "'2014-08-14'"
```

Dates and Strings need to be single quoted as per SQL.

Comment: Of course, I'm so stupid. I have gotten used to using androids SQLite methods other than raw statement. Don''t need those quotes in them.

Comment: If you were to use a preparedStatement object, then this may be simplified by using the `set*` methods.  This also prevents SQL Injection.

Answer (score 3):

Date constants need to be enclosed in single quotes:

```
" WHERE " + COLUMN_TIME_DISTANCE_ADDED + " BETWEEN " + "'2014-07-14'" + " AND " + "'2014-08-14'";
```

This problem would be more readily apparent if you printed out the SQL statement after the substitution.  That is always a good first step in trying to debug this type of problem.